# How to use sed and cut to find and replace value at certain position of line in a file

Tags: shell, unix, sed, cut

I have a case where I have to replace the number 1 with number 3 at 10th location of various lines in a stored text file. I am unable to find a way to do that. Below is sample file and code.

Sample file:

```
$ cat testdata.txt
1  43515 8 1 victor    Samuel    20190112
3215736  4 6 Michael   pristine  20180923
1  56261 1 1 John      Carter    19880712
```

```
#!/bin/sh
filename=testdata.txt
echo "reading number of line"
nol=$(cat $filename | wc -l)
flag[$nol]=''
echo "reading content of file"
for i in (1..$nol)
do
flag=($cut -c10-11 $filename)
if($flag==1)
sed 's/1/3/2'
fi
done
```

But this is not working.

Please help to resolve this.

**Updated:**

Sample Output:

```
1  43515 8 1 victor    Samuel    20190112
3215736  4 6 Michael   pristine  20180923
1  56261 3 1 John      Carter    19880712
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You need to provide a sample output too. Your description of the problem is rather terse and a bit unclear

Comment: This doesn't look like the right tools for the job. What about using a programming langauge more oriented towards string manipulation like awk, perl, or python? Would be rather simple to do it with one of those and most linux systems have all of them preinstalled.

Comment: Reason to use the shell script is that, I am using pig to store a complex data in hive external table then generating files by shell after some manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

**try this**

```
sed "s/^\(.\{8\}\) 1 \(.*\)$/\1 3 \2/g" testdata.txt > new_testdata.txt
```

If sed supports the option -i you can also edit inplace.

```
sed -i "s/^\(.\{8\}\) 1 \(.*\)$/\1 3 \2/g" testdata.txt
```

**output**

```
1  43515 8 1 victor     Samuel 20190112
3215736 4 6 Michael pristine 20180923
1  56261 3 1 John      Carter    19880712
```

**explanation**

```
s              # substitute
/^\(           # from start of line, save into arg1
.\{8\}         # the first 8 characters
\) 1 \(        # search pattern ' 1 '
.*             # save the rest into arg2
\)$/           # to the end of the line
\1 3 \2        # output: arg1 3 arg2
/g             # global on whole line
```

Comment: Some small improvements: You don't need the global flag. Matching the substring after ` 1 ` is obsolete. When `sed` supports it. the flag `-r` helps avoiding backslashes: `sed -ri 's/^(.{8}) 1 /\1 3 /' testdata.txt`

Comment: Thanks @UtLax, this helped alot. Explanation given by you helped much to understand the expression.